# App showing "Display in this area" while opening

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am facing little problem in my android app. 
When i open my android app in new notched android devices, There is a blank space at bottom of the app displaying the text "**Display in this area**" as shown in the screenshot.

Here is main xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:background="#fffafafa"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:background="#fff8f8f8"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:itemTextColor="#424242"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:theme="@style/DrawerStyle"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can i see your xml file?

Comment: You're looking for Main xml?